# postgresql: where/when criteria when selecting timestamp column

Tags: postgresql

Novice to postgresql here.  On 8.3 (not my choice, can't do anything about it for near future).

I'm selecting some "time" text strings from a table and inserting them into a view:

```
create or replace view test as (
    select 
    case 
    when desc like '%opening%' then 'opening'
    when desc like '%closing%' then 'closing'
    else n/a
    end as time_type, 
    to_timestamp(time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') where time_type = 'closing' as closing_time,
    to_timestamp(time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') where time_type = 'opening' as opening_time
  from source_table);
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 8: .../YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') where time_type = 'closing' as closing...
```

I've used this syntax before to create other views so I am confused.  Is it because my where statements are incorrectly placed? But if I place them after the from, they will be applied universally, no, and that is not what I want.

Comment: You can only have a single `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two expressions look like they should be case statements, e.g.:

```
case
when time_type = 'closing' then
  to_timestamp(time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
else null
end as closing_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the two projections beginning with `to_timestamp` to `CASE` statements as well.